# Docker build with external file

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a docker file which does a simple `dotnet restore` inside a container, essentially like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine as build-env
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
```

Now, sometimes the `dotnet restore` requires external packages, i.e. an external `nuget.config` file.

This file can be found at various locations depending on whether you are using windows/mac etc, but the operator is always expected to know where it is.

More so, this file has **sensitive information** and therefore cannot be in the repository.  All I want to do is when I do `docker build .` I want to pass that file into the docker container.  This file will not be part of the `.` context and will reside somewhere else.

Conceptually I want to do `docker build -file "c:\XXX\Nuget.Config"` and then have it available inside docker. An option could also be if I could somehow mount that file/directory into the volume **at build time**.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I have contemplated `docker-compose` so might be open to solutions using that although for now I just want to keep it simple and use `docker`

Answer (score 0):

Two easy options I can think of, depending on how sensitive the information is:

1. If it's super-sensitive you could build your binaries *outside* of docker and create your final image by copying in the binaries.
2. If you could permit sensitive information in a transient build container (but not in the final shipped image) then a multi-stage build (like [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/blob/master/dotnetapp-prod/Dockerfile)) would work. (Of course, you'd have to ensure `nuget.config` is within the `.` context before build.)